# Java generic at return type

Tags: java, generics

I have seen some code like this and unable to understand its significance:

```
public class ClassA{

public <T> void getContactName(ContactList<T> contactList){
    //do something
}    

}
```

Basically I didn't understand this. The class compiles without any error. I thought ClassA should also be made generic with parameter 'T' .

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The definition

```
public <T> void getContactName(ContactList<T> contactList){
    //do something
}
```

means that **only the method** is generic and the type with a name `T` is valid only in the scope of the method. There's no need the class to be generic if the `T` type parameter is used only in a single method.

As a side note, remember that in Java you can make generic:

- classes (except the anonymous ones)
- methods
- interfaces

but you can't make generic:

- exceptions
- anonymous classes
- enums

Comment: Won't adding <T> in method signature won't suffice ? Why do we need to add <T> before void ??

Comment: Because somewhere we have to tell Java that we will use a type named `T` and since we don't define it at class level, we do it on method level.

Comment: The `<T>` before `void` is just to declare the generic type parameter. It tells the compiler, that `T` is a generic type - without any bounds in your case.

Comment: `<T>` before `void` isn't a part of the return type. It is between the method modifiers and the return type. I agree that the syntax is a bit wierd, `public void getContactName<T>(ContactList<T> contactList)` would be more reasonable, but that's just how Sun decided to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's better explained under *Java Tutorial* on [Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) and [Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) along with *detail* examples and uses of generic methods.

here is an example (build-in `Arrays` class). Have a look at the method signature that ensures that method return type is exactly same as method arguments since class itself is not generic but you can make method as generic.

```
class Arrays {
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    ...
}
```

You can create `static generic utility methods` as mentioned above where you `don't need to create object` of the class.

Comment: Well, the return type is void. The generic parameter just ensures that both method arguments use same generic type.

Comment: sorry let me change the method.

Answer (score 1):

According to Java Language Specification:

- A type variable is an unqualified identifier. Type variables are
  introduced by generic class declarations, generic interface
  declarations, generic method declarations, and by generic constructor
  declarations.
- A class is generic if it declares one or more type variables. These
  type variables are known as the type parameters of the class. It
  defines one or more type variables that act as parameters. A generic
  class declaration defines a set of parameterized types, one for each
  possible invocation of the type parameter section. All of these
  parameterized types share the same class at runtime.
- An interface is generic if it declares one or more type variables.
  These type variables are known as the type parameters of the
  interface. It defines one or more type variables that act as
  parameters. A generic interface declaration defines a set of types,
  one for each possible invocation of the type parameter section. All
  parameterized types share the same interface at runtime.
- A method is generic if it declares one or more type variables. These
  type variables are known as the formal type parameters of the method.
  The form of the formal type parameter list is identical to a type
  parameter list of a class or interface.
- A constructor can be declared as generic, independently of whether
  the class that the constructor is declared in is itself generic. A
  constructor is generic if it declares one or more type variables.
  These type variables are known as the formal type parameters of the
  constructor. The form of the formal type parameter list is identical
  to a type parameter list of a generic class or interface.

You can use your method like this:

```
new ClassA().<String>getContactName(contactList);
```

or you can not specify the type parameter

```
new ClassA().getContactName(contactList);
```

You can read specification for further details and good faq you can find [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)